# Budget for traveling in Eastern Europe?

Tags: backpacking, hostels, eastern-europe, interrail, planning

We are planning to backpack through Eastern Europe for a month on an Interrail pass and I am trying to put together a budget estimate. Our travel path is not planned yet, but will be something like Greece->Macedonia->Serbia->Hungary->Slovakia->Czech Republic->Poland. I understand that prices will probably vary between these countries.

1. What is the average price for staying in a hostel mixed dorm (5-10 persons)?
2. How widespread is CouchSurfing, can we expect to be hosted for most of the trip?
   (We have previous CouchSurfing experiences.)
3. What budget should I estimate for food daily when cooking ourselves and buying at super markets?
4. In most of Western Europe seat reservation on fast trains is compulsory, and can become quite expensive when interrailing.

   Is this also so in Eastern Europe, and if so what is the price generally for reservations?

   Are there some trains that we should prefer to avoid compulsory seat reservations?
5. What is the average price of a double bed in a private room (at a hostel)?
6. Is there anything else budgetwise I should take into account?
7. In your experience what total budget should be set aside for such a trip, when backpacking and travelling cheaply?

Comment: The pretty much standard price for a dorm bed in Eastern Europe is €10 +/- €1. In Greece expect to pay at least twice as much, and hostels are very hard to find but exist in at least Thessaloniki.

Comment: I downvoted because I think there are too many questions in one question. Most of the questions would be fine as stand-alone questions and it would be more helpful for future searchers imo.

Comment: @victoriah: So I should make 7 different questions instead? That would be very confusing. The overall question here is: What should I expect in a budget when travelling in Eastern Europe?

Comment: A lot of the questions you want answered would be useful to other people but probably wouldn't be located in a search because it's not clear they're being asked: "In most of Western Europe seat reservation on fast trains is compulsory, and can become quite expensive when interrailing. Is this also so in Eastern Europe, and if so what is the price generally for reservations? Is there some trains that we should prefer to avoid compulsory seat reservations?"

Comment: @bjarkef: In addition, if you make 7 question users will be more motivated to answer. For  instance, I could respond a couple of question, but not all. BTW, I was in Czech Republic, Poland, Hungary and Slovakia last March and my expenses were 540 € per person travelling 2 persons along a month (sleeping in hostels and cooking there sometimes)

Comment: @victoriah: http://bit.ly/wzPIwv - Searching returns quite useful results, for your example. (See the second search result, at time of writing.) This discussion is really turning meta now, and should probably not be continued here.

Comment: q4 has the answer on interrail website, q1&5 open a guidebook, scan the housing pages for 10 minutes and you'll find it, and maybe you can group q6&7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm form Croatia and know a bit about this region so here goes (you didn't mention Croatia for your itinerary but I would suggest you visit our coast; I'm presuming you are traveling in the summer time):

1. You will need from 13 to 20 euros a night for a bed in a dorm in a hostel.
2. It is widespread in larger cities but it depends on what season it is. A lot of people go to the seaside and are not available for CS then.
3. Depending on how many of you are in a travel group, you would need about 20-40 euros a day for two self-prepared meals (pasta with some sauces or something) for 4-5 people.
4. For traveling locally, you almost never need a reservation but if you are traveling internationally, you will always need to book a seat or berth in a train.
5. 25 euros and up...
6. Perhaps budget for visiting museums, monuments, drinking, partying. Everything is more expensive in summer time and drinks are from 1.5 to 3 euros for half a liter of beer in a bar and from 3 to 5 euros for a 0.25 L bottle of beer in clubs...
7. I would suggest taking 1200 to 1500 euros per person for a months travel, including sleeping, eating, monuments and late night drinking every couple of days...

Answer (score 3):

Subquestion 4. - Train reservations:

I took several trains in Eastern Europe [last year](http://peter.hahndorf.eu/trip/2011/mapgm.html) including some international ones. I never made any reservations for day time seats. I took a few night trains in the Ukraine and from Bulgaria to Turkey. For these I bought the tickets for the berth the day before.

I did not have an interrail pass, and I think you have to pay extra for a berth on a night train with your pass.

In general I think there are not as many 'super fast trains' in Eastern Europe as in the west.

Here's a [good list](http://www.interrailnet.com/planning/train-seat-reservations/reservation-fees) of international trains that require a reservation.

Answer (score 3):

Poland:

1. Between 8-20 euros for a night for a bed in a dorm in a hostel. Depends on the town and if it is high season or not.
2. Not really widespread
3. 10-15 euros per day if you'll buy in supermarkets.
4. National railway operator is called PKP. You do not need a reservation of Regio/InterRegio/TLK trains (the cheaper ones). Crossing the border in a train is quite expensive. It's better to get to the border, cross it yourself and continue with another train.
5. 20-40 euro
6. Entrance to Museums and national parks can be paid, but it's not expensive.
7. I think about 700 euro for a month should be enough.